# How to know if markers on the map touch each other

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am building an application which uses Google Maps. When displaying the map, I'm also adding markers. Is there a way to see if there are 2 markers that touch each other, meaning if a part of a marker is on top of another marker? My goal is to be able to find that out and then make them a single bigger marker instead of 2 different markers.

The answer should depend somehow on the marker's icon size and the current map zoom since if I zoom out, there's a bigger chance they might overlap.

Comment: you have the answer, you said it, marker size and position and map zoom.
i mean you can can make a study and develop and algorithm that depends on map current zoom and the 2 markers position and there respectives sizes in dp then you will simply pass all these parameters to a method and it will return true or false

Comment: @MohammadHaidar I'm not sure how to get the icon size and I don't know how to make a calculation from the icon size and zoom if they touch each other or not

Comment: i dont know either but am telling you the way for you to know it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be a library made by Google which clusters a set of markers together automatically when they are close to one another.

The library is the marker clustering utility and instruction can be found here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering